# Is there any out-of-the-box mapper from duration string to milis?

Tags: java

I store some duration values in properties, such as "period: 30s" or "period: 15m" and then convert it to milliseconds in my method. 
Are there any Java built-in mappers from such format to millis ?

For example:

```
long millis = mapToMillis("15s") // millis variable should be 15000 here
long milllis2 = mapToMillis("1m") // millis2 variable shoul be 60000 here
```

I looked for such mappers in Duration class but none of them match my problem.

Answer (score 1):

[`Duration.parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) does offer this feature. The how-to is mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-). You just need to store the values in the format mentioned there.

Example:

```
System.out.println(
        Duration.parse("PT15S").toMillis()
);
```

prints `15000`.

If you need to deal with dates instead of time, you can use the equivalent parse method in [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your duration values are *time-based amounts* (i.e. seconds, minutes, days, ...), you can use the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) type.

With the method

```
private static long mapToMillis(String duration) {
    return Duration.parse("PT" + duration).toMillis();
}
```

the code snippet

```
long millis = mapToMillis("15s"); // millis variable should be 15000 here
long milllis2 = mapToMillis("1m"); // millis2 variable shoul be 60000 here
System.out.println(millis);
System.out.println(milllis2);
```

prints out

```
15000
60000
```